# Electron Running Older Version of Source

Tags: node.js, caching, electron

I'm building an electron application for Windows. For a few days, I had no problem altering my source code and running `electron .` from the command line and all was well.

Now, when I do that, I see an older version of the code running. The changes I make to my source code now have no effect. I thought that the old code might be cached in `%APPDATA%\Electron`, and I've deleted everything that I found in that folder to no effect. But I am still seeing the same old version of the code run. I've also tried `%LocalAppData%\electron` to the same effect.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can get electron to run the current version of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. This has two parts.

The name of the folder for the cache for my electron application is derived from the `name` attribute in `package.json`. Though deleting that wasn't sufficient for me to get around the problem that I was experiencing.

Since the same source code is being edited by Windows and mac users, I had enabled the Case Sensitive file system for folder that has the source code. This way, if there were ever an inconsistency in how a file was named and how it was referenced that I would see it on Windows before it was checked-in and made available to the mac users.

Visual Studio Code is doing some type of internal caching of the source code. When I detected that a file had inconsistent casing, I changed it. From then on, when I made an attempt to save, VS Code was updating its cached version but not the version of the file that was in the targeted folder.

The moral of the story, VS Code on Windows is **not** compatible with case sensitive files. I just moved to using a different application for editing (Visual Studio) since I don't know how to get Visual Studio Code to clear it's cache.

Comment: I find it interesting that this should be the case. After all, Linux and Mac filesystems are case-sensitive by default and VS Code obviously works there. I'd expect them to have a single codebase for the file-saving logic for all three systems. Have you considered raising this issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues)?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner - I had not considered it. But now that you've suggested it I think I shall.